# Regex function to change url to another

Tags: php, regex

Im totally new to regex. I need your help.

What is the regex function for changing the below url to url listed downside?
How to use that regex function in PHP.

```
https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/393656_257350694313804_126044397444435_712409_344887174_s.jpg
```

TO

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s320x320/393656_257350694313804_126044397444435_712409_344887174_n.jpg
```

OR

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s480x480/393656_257350694313804_126044397444435_712409_344887174_n.jpg
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think u can use a couple of str_replace here instead of regexp

Comment: Is the original url layout always going to be `[domain]/[folder]/[image]`?

Comment: yes structure is always same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$size = "s320x320";
$url = preg_replace("#https://(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\_s.jpg#i", "https://$1/$2/$size/$3_n.jpg", $url);
$url = str_replace("-photos-", "-sphotos-", $url);
```

This code is untested, but should work. The third line, `str_replace`, is used to make the regex simpler. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace( '#^(.*?)photos(.*)(/[^/]*?)_s.jpg$#', '$1sphotos$2/s320x320$3_n.jpg', $url );
```

Comment: domain and filename are also differ

Comment: Thanks. Also https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net should converted to https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net and _s.jpg should changed to _n.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me try to answer with some code

```
$url = 'https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/393656_257350694313804_126044397444435_712409_344887174_s.jpg';
$str = array('fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4', '_s');
$rep1 = array('fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s320x320', '_n');
$rep2 = array('fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s480x480', '_n');

//TO
$url1 = str_replace($str, $rep1, $url);
//OR
$url2 = str_replace($str, $rep2, $url);
```

Comment: Thanks. is it possible change hardcoded string (fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4) to dynamic?